# How to return custom datatable input value

Tags: jquery, input, datatable

I have a DataTable with a generated input field and button. When I click the button, I want to console.log the value inside of the input field.. can someone help? Here's my generated table:

```
var productsTable = $('#productsTable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/products/",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Product Code", "data": "product_code" },
        { "title": "Supplier", "data": "supplier" },
        { "title": "Category", "data": "category"},
        { "title": "Description", "data": "description"},
        { "title": "Price", "data": "invoice_price"},
        { "title": "Quantity", "defaultContent": "<input class='quantity' type='number'>" },
        { "title": "", "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-primary'>Click Me!</button>" },
    ]
   });
```

And here is my attempt at the click event:

```
$("#productsTable tbody").on('click', 'button', function() {
    var quantity = $(this).parents("tr:first").find('.quantity input').val();
    console.log(quantity); // returns undefined
 });
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please

```
var quantity = $(this).parents("tr:first").find('.quantity').val();
```

Comment: That works well! I have a another similar issue - when I click the button, I need to return the `product_code` as well. `var product_code = productsTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data().product_code;` works when the table is full-size but does not work when the table is in responsive mode... do you have any idea how I can return the `product_code` in responsive mode?? Thanks in advance!